# Matlab - No luck when using 'xtick' to change axis on graph

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following graph in Matlab:

[image]

I have tried using '`xTick`' and '`yTick`' to make the axis on each subplot the same, but it's not accomplishing what I would like it to. I also want the both axes of each subplot to share the same range so that I can easily compare the graphs. (i.e. ranging from 0 - 20, in y, and 0 - 400 in x).

I'm not sure how to change this.

My attempt is below. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
figure()
hold on
subplot (1,2,1);
% xlim([0 400]);
% ylim([0 25]);
graph_made = [num_calls_made];
plot (graph_made);
title('Number of calls made')
xlabel('ID Number of caller');
ylabel('Number of calls');
set(gca, 'XTick', [0:100:400]);
set(gca, 'YTick', [0:5:20]);

subplot (1,2,2);
graph_rec = [num_calls_received];
plot (graph_rec);
title('Number of calls received')
xlabel('ID Number of caller');
ylabel('Number of calls');
set(gca, 'XTick', [0:100:400]);
set(gca, 'YTick', [0:5:20]);
hold off
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the axes limits to stay linked as a user interactively zooms or pans, you can also use the `linkaxes` command...

```
subplot(1,2,1)
% your plotting code here...
ax = gca;  %get the handle to the current axis

subplot(1,2,2)
% your plotting code here...
ax(end+1) = gca;  %get the handle to the current axis

linkaxes(ax);  %this will link both the x and y axes.
```

Comment: You can also use the return value from `subplot` instead of making an extra call to `gca`

Answer (score 2):

`XTick` and `YTick` only change where the labels on axes go, not the limits of the axes. To change those, you have to use `axis` (or `xlim` and `ylim`):

```
axis([0 400 0 20]) %// [xmin xmax ymin ymax]
```

Comment: Ah, yes thank you very much! That has solved my problem. I didn't realise I had to do xlim and ylim for each subplot